# Time triggered Azure Function and queue processing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues, poison-queue

I have a Function called once a day processing all messages in a queue. But I would like to also have the retries and poison messages logic as with the Queue Trigger. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: You'd have to do it manually I guess. Why not just use Queue Trigger? You could schedule your messages not to be processed before time X.

Comment: The business like to have control of the timing.

Comment: How would you schedule after time X with a Queue Trigger?

Comment: You can set `initialVisibilityDelay` while sending the message, see [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueue_AddMessageAsync_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_CloudQueueMessage_System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Queue_QueueRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I cannot use this for the batch processing behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at that point you function is purely a timer triggered function and from there you are no different than a console app in terms of how you would have to process messages from a queue with your own client connection, message loop, retrying and dead lettering (poison) logic. It's honestly just not the right tool for that job.

One approach I *suppose* you could consider if you wanted to be creative so that you could benefit from using an Azure Function's built in queue trigger behavior while still controlling what time the queue is processed is actually starting and stopping the function instance itself via something like Azure Scheduler. Scheduling the starting of the function is pretty straightforward and, once started, it will immediately begin draining the queue. The challenge is knowing how to stop it. The Azure Function runtime with the queue binding won't ever stop on its own as it's reading off the queue using a pull model so it's just gonna sit there waiting for new messages to arrive, right? So stopping it is really a question of understanding the need of the business. Do you stop once there's no more messages left for that day? Do you stop at a specific time of day? Etc. There's no correct answer here, it's totally domain specific, but whatever that answer is will dictate the exact approach taken.

Honestly, as I said earlier on, I'm not sure this is the right tool for the job. Yeah, it's nice that you get the retry and poison handling, but you're really going against the grain of the runtime. I would personally suggest you look into scheduling this simple console executable, executed in a task-like fashion using Azure Container Instances ([some docs on that approach here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-restart-policy)). If you were counting on the auto-scale of Azure Functions, that's totally something you can get from Azure Container Instances as well.

Comment: Thanks, i agree with your answer. I ended up with a queue-trigger inserting inserting the message into a Azure table. A time trigger would later process this like a queue of tasks.